# Django query by filter different attributes from slug

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-urls

I have a model with lots of attributes. I want to query the model by filters in attritbutes. The problems is that I have to write lots of function to query by different attributes.

models.py

```
class ETF(models.Model):
    ticker = models.CharField(max_length=6, blank=False, db_index=True, unique=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    region = models.ManyToManyField(Region)
    sector = models.ManyToManyField(Sector)
    industry = models.ManyToManyField(Industry)
    # Even more attributes here

class Theme(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, unique=True) 
    slug = models.SlugField(default="", null=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I am writing a function to filter ETF by attritbutes.
Here is Views.py:

```
class Categories_selector():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def theme(self, category_slug):
        return ETF.objects.filter(theme__slug=category_slug).order_by('-aum')
    def sector(self, category_slug):
        return ETF.objects.filter(sector__slug=category_slug).order_by('-aum')
    def region(self, category_slug):
        return ETF.objects.filter(region__slug=category_slug).order_by('-aum')
   # more function here

c_object = Categories_selector() 

def get_etf_list(request, categories_slug, category_slug):        
    filtered_results = getattr(c_object, categories_slug)(category_slug)
    return render(request, "etf/list_etf.html", {
        "ETFs": filtered_results
    })
```

urls.py

```
path("<slug:categories_slug>/<slug:category_slug>/", views.get_etf_list)
```

Is there better way to do this? I feel like this is really dumb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query these together with:

```
def get_etf_list(request, categories_slug, category_slug):
    if categories_slug in ('theme', 'sector', 'region'):
        return ETF.objects.filter(
            **{f'{categories_slug}__slug': category_slug}
        ).order_by('-aum')
        return render(request, "etf/list_etf.html", {
            "ETFs": filtered_results
        })
    else:  # return an error page
        pass
```

Comment: What is this "**{f'{categories_slug}__slug'=category_slug}" called? This is new to me. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @John: this is [*dictionary unpacking*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/#id6). `f(**{'x': 4})` is equivalent to `f(x=4)`.

Comment: Thank you! for anyone else reading this, the = should be :

Comment: @John: aaarggghhh... that was a typo, thanks!